# How can we structure the continuous form of 'theft'?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I am trying to form a sentence that tells about how someone is stealing something at the moment. Can I say - "A theft is taking place right now." ?
'Taking place' sounds improper, and too formal.
Is there a better way to structure this sentence?

Comment: It's fine. You can use *Someone is stealing x* if you want to be less formal.

Comment: *He's ripping me off!!!*

Comment: One can also say _going on (right now)_. The `Time is Motion` metaphor theme uses _go_ to mean 'continue', as in _Is that motor going?_ And _What's going on?_ is a normal greeting. It can be used to describe any event or process, as long as it's durative and some activity is involved.

Comment: Thanks to @John Lawler for the best suggestion. Here's my attempt to put these synonyms into a least formal - most formal continuum:   going on --- taking place - happening --- being committed --- occurring --- transpiring. So 'taking place' is pretty informal. Don't be put off by the multi-word-verb forms. I imagine that 'take place' sounds rather odd to a learner, but it's very common, and better regarded as an idiom rather than verb + noun.

Comment: Another option would be “A theft is *in progress* right now.”

Answer (score -3):

Thiefing is not possible so stealing. If you need the word theft ...it is just taking place or happening right now.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. [Thieving is certainly possible](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/thieve), I'm afraid.